# Short, periodic WiFi signal loss in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking

I noticed that my WiFi dies for a short amount of time at regular 5-10 second intervals. This is shown in the network monitor widget below:

[image: wifi-shortages]

This is particularly problematic when using Skype. Does anybody know what is causing this?

I am using a Dell M6800 laptop, with a Broadcom WiFi device.

EDIT:

I tried changing the channels in my router, but that did not seem to help. Every time I changed the channel, there was a short period of no wifi, and then the same behavior began once more.

[image: changed-channels]

Comment: Cell phones or other devices periodically polling for a connection could be interrupting, even if not on the same channel (due to harmonics etc.). You might test the effect of changing WiFi channel. Please let me know if that helps.

Comment: I tried changing the channels in my router settings, but that did not help. After a short period of no wifi, the wifi comes back, and periodic shortages start happening again (see screenshot, where I changed the channel 3 times).

Comment: Are you running any kind of Wi-Fi scanner software (app, widget, plug-in, etc.)?

Comment: I am. However, it seems unlikely that this is causing the issue, as the update frequency is much higher than the shortage frequency. Also, the shortage does not always happen -- in some cases I see an entirely smooth graph without shortages.

Comment: (I am using the network analyzer from the RainMeter widget)